# Nunit tests fails when running continuous integration build on team foundation service

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs, continuous-integration, nunit

I have followed a couple of guides on how to get nunit to work on TFS (the cloud version)

http://www.mytechfinds.com/articles/software-testing/6-test-automation/72-running-nunit-tests-from-team-foundation-server-2012-continuous-integration-build

http://walkingthestack.blogspot.sg/2013/04/using-nunit-for-your-tests-in-team.html

However, after setting up everything, I'm still getting this error message:

```
Exception Message: The path '$/Plan.Ess.sln' could not be converted to a local path. Make sure this path is relative to the 'src' folder on the build machine or specify a full server path. (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core.LocalPathProvider.GetLocalPath(String incomingPath)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\a\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.
```

1) `$/Plan.Ess.sln` is what I keyed in my Build Definitions > Edit Build Definition > Process > 1. Solution to build

2) I'm not sure why it's refering to C:\a\bin

I'm not sure if I have "`Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework settings are appropiate and try again`" (Solution from the 2nd link) But I have already pointed the build controller to the folder containing the nunit test adapters & dlls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found out the reason. I was pointing to the wrong path. I replaced `$/Plan.Ess.sln` with `Plan.Ess.sln` and it works.